# How to get every params in an object in Express?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I want to know whether there is any way where I can get the whole object without using `req.params.users` but I can get everything send from react-native because the URL would be very long such as `https://example.com/createUser/myname/myrole/myic/myaddress/mybirthday`. I would like to shorter it to `https://example.com/createUser`. I tried `req.body` but cannot get any data compare `req.params.name`.

index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const user = express();
user.use(cors());

user.post('/createUser/:name/:role/:ic/:address/:birthday', usersEndpoint.createUser);
```

users.js

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const db = admin.firestore();
exports.setUserRole = function (req, res) {

    const name = req.params.name;   
    const role = req.params.role;
    const ic = req.params.ic;
    const address = req.params.address;
    const birthday = req.params.birthday;    

    //......others code
};
```

Comment: Please elaborate what you need??whether `name` is undefined?? Or you are trying to send all `req.params` into `req.body`??

Comment: What I mean is I want to shorten the URL because there is too many params which is causing the URL string to be too long. I want to know whether there is any other way that can shorten the URL string.

Comment: I don't understand why you're putting all these parameters INSIDE the url for a POST in the first place?  That's the wrong use of URLs for a POST.  These should be in the body, not in the URL.  That needs to be first fixed on the client side (which you don't show us the code for) by treating the data as formData, not as something that goes in the URL and then make a corresponding change on the server where, with the proper configuration and route declaration and middleware, they properties will all be named properties in req.body and the URL should just be `https://example.com/createUser`.

Comment: TLDR - Post the data from the client as formData and it will be in the body where it belongs and the URL can just be `https://example.com/createUser` as it should be and then with the right `bodyParser` middleware, you can just access the properties in `req.body`.  Post data belongs in the body, not in the URL.  Fix your client to send it properly and then fix the server to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already found the solution by shortening `https://example.com/createUser` your url and pass params in `req.body`

But the problem as you stated `I tried req.body but cannot get any data` , that's because you have to use `bodyparser` as follows:

```
user.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}))
user.use(bodyParser.json())
```

and then if you access `req.body` in your route you can get the data

Comment: So cors() no need to use until? Only use body parser?

Comment: @raynne You can use cors() also